# How to use preview-email or something similar in e2e tests?

Tags: javascript, angular, email, express, testing

I have an angular frontend with an express backend. My app is heavily dependent on using email because of write restrictions on the database. I'm writing some angular/protractor e2e specs, in which I would like to include the the email previews generated by [preview-email](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preview-email) on the express side.

The problem is that the email previews do not open in the automated chrome window used by protractor. I figure this is a core part of how [opn](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn) works, which is what preview-email uses to open the emails. Opn uses `xdg-open` on my linux machine, causing the file to open in a new chrome instance or a tab of an existing chrome window when one is already open, but not in the automated chrome window. Is there a way to have the preview emails open in the automated protractor/selenium/webdriver window, or another way to test the contents of the generated emails in e2e specs?

A code snippet in order to clarify how preview-email is used in the various environments:

```
return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'acceptance':
      return resolve();

    case 'production':
        transporter.sendMail(message, function (error, response) {
          if (error) {
            return reject(error);
          }
          return resolve();
      });

    default:
      previewEmail(message).catch(console.error);
      return resolve();
  }
});
```

So in the default case (the dev environment) previewEmail is used, causing a new tab to be opened in the developers default browser. In the production env nodemailer will send the email. In the staging (acceptance) enviroment nothing will happen.

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough details. This totally depends on how things work in your app. https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn is Node package, it would open an app on server side, so it's hardly applicable here.

Comment: What other information would you like to have?

Comment: How exactly is this 'normal' window created? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added more information. Is the problem more clear now? I am completely willing to provide more information, but I would not know what to add.

Comment: What kind of application is it? Is it desktop app? The thing you're describing requires a user to run both frontend (browser) and backend (node) on his/her own machine, similarly to Electron. Is it really so?

Comment: This is a web app. I am running the angular and express apps on my local machine as a developer. Preview-email is only enabled in my dev environment. In the production environment actual real emails are sent and the front and backend are ran in a VM.


I am setting up e2e testing (aka integration testing, feature testing). Since emails are a large part of the functionality of the app in production, I also want to test then in my dev env, and eventually in my CI/testing env. Thank you for thinking along with me.

Comment: Do you mean that in production opn is still used but launches something like `mail`, while in development it launches `chrome`?

Comment: I've added a code snippet to the original question to clarify.

Comment: So, in e2e tests (is this what acceptance env is for?) you can do something non-intrusive that you can easily track in test runner (writing to temp files). If you have separate backend tests for a mailer with something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-stub , you can just stub mails entirely in e2e and trust backend tests on that.

Comment: I created a 'sent mail' part of my website for administrators to monitor all automated emails that the system sends.  Many test scenarios use this to continue automated testing, for example, testing the 'forgot password' feature to retrieve the randomly generated reset password link. - You probably want to build this, it's good for testing and good for live administration.